# Parent - Child Sorting is MySQL and Displaying with Relationship Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has a category table like this:

```
id      name             parent
2043    Company Ops      (null)
2044    Station 1        2043
2045    Station 2        2043
2049    Station 3        2043
2050    Station 1 sub    2044
2047    FM Stuff         (null)
2046    New Const        2047
2048    Blighted         2047
```

I am trying to sort it with the Collase funtion using:

```
select *
from Table1
order by coalesce(parent, id), parent is not null, id
```

I loaded the SQL into SQL fiddle using this as the table builder.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(20),  `parent` varchar(4))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `name`, `parent`)
VALUES
    (2045, 'Station 2', '2043'),
    (2043, 'Company Ops', NULL),
    (2044, 'Station 1', '2043'),
    (2050, 'Station 1 sub', '2044'),
    (2048, 'Blighted', '2047'),
    (2049, 'Station 3', '2043'),
    (2047, 'FM Stuff', NULL),
    (2046, 'New Const', '2047')
;
```

I tried playing with the SQL, but cannot seem to get it to do what I want. When it gets to the third level (station 1 sub), it does not sort it appropriately.

**Two Questions:**

1. How can I sort a multi-level parent child relationship table in order of their relationships.  In this case, Station 1 sub should be under Station 1.

2). How can I show the level of parent child relationship using something like dashes.  Either in MySQL or PHP?

```
Company Ops 
-Station 1   
-Station 2  
-Station 3 
--Station 1 sub
FM Stuff 
-New Const
-Blighted
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the fiddle?

Comment: This kind of sorting is imho easier done with PHP. Create a multidimensional array pushing every child into the parent. Then you have the right order and you know how many steps you're down the ladder in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to walk the graph in any way you prefer. For example, the query below starts with the root nodes and goes down to the children nodes:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select id, name, parent, cast(concat('/', id) as char(100)) as path, 1 as lvl
  from table1 where parent is null
 union all
  select t.id, concat(repeat('-', n.lvl), t.name), t.parent, 
    concat(n.path, '/', t.id), n.lvl + 1
  from n
  join table1 t on t.parent = n.id
)
select * from n order by path
```

Result:

```
 id    name             parent  path             lvl 
 ----- ---------------- ------- ---------------- --- 
 2043  Company Ops      null    /2043            1   
 2044  -Station 1       2043    /2043/2044       2   
 2050  --Station 1 sub  2044    /2043/2044/2050  3   
 2045  -Station 2       2043    /2043/2045       2   
 2049  -Station 3       2043    /2043/2049       2   
 2047  FM Stuff         null    /2047            1   
 2046  -New Const       2047    /2047/2046       2   
 2048  -Blighted        2047    /2047/2048       2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pMPS97dZbGR8Up7foxv1dW/0).

Again, this is just an example. You can walk the graph in any direction: up/down, bottom/up, by level, etc.